# accessing heroku config var in my React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I have defined a config var "BASE_URL" in my Heroku app and I'm trying to access it in my React app as

```
process.env.BASE_URL
```

but it gives me undefined when I console.log it as it seems to be not existing.
How can I access Heroku config vars in my React app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [module that loads environment variables](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). Then,

```
require('dotenv').config()
...
console.log(process.env.BASE_URL);
```

Check this [post](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5), pretty useful.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, do you have any other option for it?

Comment: This works for backend and local development, but for deployment to Heroku, see Elmo Allén's answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you use Create React App (or react-scripts), prepend the variable with `REACT_APP_`, for instance, `REACT_APP_BASE_URL`, and Create React App [automatically uses its value during the build process](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables), making it then accessible in the `process.env.`

Note that the value is determined at build time, based on the envs on the machine or process that does the building. If building is done by pushing to Heroku, as it is normally in Heroku React apps, then by the envs that were set in Heroku at the build time.

If you're not using Create React App, and using Webpack, you'll need to use [Webpack EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) to define the envs you need.

Note: You **must not** reveal any secrets, e.g. API keys or passwords, in this way. The actual contents of all these variables are appended to the production build files themselves and can be freely accessed by just reading the public-facing code files.

Comment: good day, do you mean api keys or any secrets should not be stored any of .env files right?

Comment: I don't mean .env files in general. I specifically mean the .env files in the frontend build, and the variables that start with `REACT_APP_`, because they are transferred into the built .js files. Other .env variables are only available during the build time and stay secure.

Of course, API keys are useless during build time. And there's no way to securely give them to the frontent code in any way, be it .env files or not. They should only stay in the backend, where they're safe in the .env files (as long as you store your development files securely).

Comment: Important thing to note here is that React embeds the values of env vars during build time, not during run time. So when setting the value of a config var in Heroku (make sure to prepend with REACT_APP_) you'll need to rebuild and redeploy your app to have the new var be available to it.

Comment: @elm you saved my day. I could not find this easily with Google search.

Comment: Should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

First install dotenv using yarn/npm

```
yarn add dotenv
```

or

```
npm install dotenv
```

Then create a **.env** file in parent directory of src folder 
and then add your key in .env file prefixed REACT_APP_ like

```
REACT_APP_YOUR_API=15dw8...
```

Now in your app.js configure dotenv

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Now you can access your environmental variables with prefix process.env.REACT_APP_ like

```
 process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_API
```

**you may need to restart the development server**

Answer (score 0):

for react es6 use

import {} from 'dotenv/config'